# How many incongruent primitive roots does 13 have?

Tags: number-theory

How many incongruent primitive roots does $13$ have:

So far I know that $\phi(\phi(13)) = \phi(12) = 4,$ so there would be $4$ primitive roots. And a RRS mod $13$ is $ \{1,2,3,...,12 \}.$ But I am not sure where to go from here to find the incongruent primitive roots. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $13$ is small, you could brute-force it. But if you have found one primitive root, do you know how to get the others from it?

Comment: The only candidates are the quadratic non-residues. That cuts down on the work. There are further shortcuts, which are not worth using here.

Answer (score 1):

The four incongruent primitive roots of $13$ are $g^k$ for $g$ a primitive root and $k$ coprime with $12$, that is, $k=1,5,7,11$. They can also be given by $\pm g, \pm g^5$ because $g^6=-1$.